# Getting a value from the top most rule in a mid/bottom one

Tags: c, bison

I'm doing my little own language and I'm trying to make there be blocks, but I'm quite stuck on how to get track of the current block (as I need to know which one a variable was created in and so-on blah blah).

My grammar file looks something like this (for simplicity's sake, it's not the whole code):

```
%{
    struct Node *nodest = NULL;
    struct Node *currentblock = NULL;
%}

%start source

%%

source
    : stmts { nodest = block($1); currentblock = nodest; }
    ;

stmts
    : stmt
    | stmts stmt
    ;

stmt
    : expr_stmt
    | iter_stmt
    | select_stmt
    | comp_stmt
    ;

expr_stmt
    : ';'
    | expr ';'
    ;

expr
    : binary_expr
    | assign_expr
    | call_expr
    | decl_expr
    | init_expr
    | VAR_IDENT
    | INTEGER
    | '(' expr ')'
    ;

comp_stmt
    : '{' '}'
    | '{' stmts '}' { $$ = block($2); currentblock = $$; }
    ;

decl_expr
    : type VAR_IDENT  { $$ = declaration($1, $2, currentblock) }
    ;
/* ... */

type
    : TYPE_INT
    ;
```

And that won't work, obviously, because `nodest` (being a block node that holds every other node) is actually given some value at the very end of creating the AST, so it's NULL for the rest of time, so `currentblock` can't be used like in `decl_expr`, because it's NULL at the time.

So my question is: how could I get the value (to where it points to or whatever) of `nodest` later on in the code?

Or, if it's not really possible, could you give me some notes/hints on how could I get this going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action code in a rule is executed when a rule is reduced, so if you want actions earlier in the process you need to put them on rules that are reduced earlier.  Both yacc and bison allow you to introduce anonymous epsilon rules by just putting an extra action earlier in the right side of a rule.  So you can do something like:

```
source: { $$ = currentblock = nodest = empty_block(); } stmts
        { $$ = add_to_block($1, $2); }

comp_stmt:
    '{' { $$ = currentblock = empty_block(); } stmts '}'
    { $$ = add_to_block($2, $3); }
;
```

Note that when you create you blocks early like this, you have to create them as empty (since you haven't yet parsed anything that goes into the block) and then add stuff to them later.  It might make more sense to add each stmt to the current block as you parse it (in which case you need to ensure that currentblock really is the current block rather than the last block:

```
source: { currentblock = nodest = empty_block(); } stmts ;

stmts: /* empty*/
     | stmts stmt { add_to_block(currentblock, $2; }

comp_stmt:
    '{' { $$ = currentblock; currentblock = empty_block(); } stmts '}'
    { $$ = currentblock; currentblock = $2 }
;
```